How to find the collection address to which it belongs through the nftmint account? How to write it in the backend Anchor
Please use the latest method and add the cargo configuration.
use mpl_token_metadata::state::Metadata  

let nft_metadata: Metadata = Metadata::from_account_info(&ctx.accounts.nft_metadata_account.to_account_info())?;
let collection =nft_metadata.collection.ok_or(MyError::NftNotAllowed)?;

require!(pool_account.allowed_nft_collections.contains(&collection.key), MyError::NftNotAllowed);

I thought about it this way, but it gave me an error saying use mpl_token_metadata::state::Metadata couldn't find state in mpl_token_metadata.
My Cargo.toml is as follows:
anchor-lang = "0.29.0"
anchor-spl = { version = "0.29.0"}
mpl-token-metadata = "4.0.1" 

Therefore, I am asking for a configuration that works.



this is new code.thanks to Jimii.I am so happy that i can help other and other can help me

If the mint address contains Metadata added to it through the Metadata program, you can get this from the metadata account
The Metadata Account contains an optional Collection field which contains the address of the collection if supplied.
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Dummy<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub metadata_account: Account<'info, MetadataAccount>,
}

if let Some(collection) = ctx.accounts.metadata_account.collection.clone() {
      msg!("This is the collection key {:?}", collection.key);
  } else {
      msg!("mint not part of a collection");
 }

ref: https://docs.rs/mpl-token-metadata/latest/mpl_token_metadata/accounts/struct.Metadata.html

I don't want to pass the metadata account. I have the PDA public key using let (metadata_key, _) = Metadata::find_pda(&nft_mint_key);, and I want to find the account's data via the public key, then deserialize the data to get the collection key. How do I do that?"

how to import MetadataAccount in mpl-token-metadata = "4.0.1" ?.not found in mpl_token_metadata::accounts::MetadataAccount and mpl_token_metadata::states::MetadataAccount ;
